# .NET Core 2.2 Assembly FileLoadException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-assembly

I want to migrate my project in `.NET Framework 4.0` to `.NET Core 2.2`.
But I have an error in my program execution.

My project want to load a `.dll` with the `Assembly` class, it's working fine with `.NET Framework 4.0` but not with `.NET Core 2.2`.

It's throwing the `FileLoadException` with the message `Could not load file or assembly 'LibName, Version=3.0.4.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'`.

Is there a missing package in the project?

```
try
{
    var pathDll = Path.Combine(path, "LibName.dll");
    Assembly.LoadFrom(pathDll);
}
catch (FileLoadException ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

My NuGet packages installed in Solution:

[image: My NuGet packages installed in Solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also calling assembly this way in .NET Core 2.1 and it works. Did you check path if it's correct? If path is relative, try to use absolute one - in .NET Core path of executable is a bit different when starting from Visual Studio.

By the way, consider using "throw" instead of "throw ex" in catch block, if you want to keep stack trace.

Comment: Same result with absolute path. Maybe the `dll` is 32 bits and must be allowed by the `.NET Core` project?

Comment: Yup, this is possible. I reproduced it. Can you recompile LibName.dll as 64-bit?

Comment: The DLL was compiled with `AnyCpu` option. I recompiled it as 64-bit and now it's working fine. The default value of `AnyCpu` is 32-bits ? I will have to inform myself.. Thank you

Comment: AnyCPU should be 64-bit by default, unless "Preferred 32-bit" is checked.